# How to change the called element color and text using if else condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Problem: While clicking continue button i want to change the color of first link black and remaining two links ash. While clicking continue button second time  I want to change the color of second link black and remaining two links ash. Same need to take place for third time and additionally on third time the continue button change to save.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav2">
    <div class="navtxt container">
        <ol>
            <li id="navlnk">Assess your risk tolerance</li>
            <div id="b" class="fif"><a href="#navlnk1" onclick="changeColor('navlnk1'); return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 20px;"></span></a></div>
            <li id="navlnk1">View your plan</li>
            <div id="b" class="fif"><a href="#navlnk2" onclick="changeColor('navlnk2'); return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 20px;"></span></a></div>
            <li id="navlnk2">Open account</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' name='add' onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("continue").value++; value='+'
if (value==1){
    document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "#000";
}
else if(value==2){
    document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#000";
}
else if(value==3)
{
    document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "#000";
    document.getElementById('navlnk2').inner.html = "Save";

}
```

}

Comment: where is the continue button?

Comment: just maintain a state and you can use continue as well as back functionality

Comment: Sir, I dint get it

Comment: Sir i didnt get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code using jquery :

```
 <style>
        .black{
            color: black;
        }
        .hash{
            color:darkkhaki;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="nav2 container">
        <div class="navtxt container">
            <ol>
                <li id="navlnk"><a  href="#navlnk1"><span style="padding-left: 20px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>Assess your risk tolerance</a></li>
                <li id="navlnk1"><a href="#navlnk2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="padding-left: 20px;" ></span>View your plan</a></li>
                <li id="navlnk2"><a  href="#navlnk2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="padding-left: 20px;"></span>Open account</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <input type='button' name='add' class="btn" value="Continue" id="continue"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var cnt = 0;
            $('#continue').on("click", function () {
                var nav = $('#navlnk a');
                var nav1 = $('#navlnk1 a');
                var nav2 = $('#navlnk2 a');
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    $(nav).addClass('black');
                    $(nav2).addClass('hash');
                    $(nav1).addClass('hash');
                }
                else if (cnt == 1)
                {
                    alert('dsd');
                    $(nav).removeClass('black').addClass('hash');
                    $(nav1).removeClass('hash').addClass('black');
                    cnt++;
                }
               else if(cnt == 3) {
                   $(nav1).removeClass('black').addClass('hash');
                   $(nav2).removeClass('hash').addClass('black');
                    $(this).val('Save');
                }
                cnt++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function like this :

```
function changeColor(type) {
      if (type == 'navlnk1') {
               //add color on first div
               document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "#000";
        } else {
                //add color on second div
                document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "#000";
              }
   }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: What is `GetMsg` ,`loadingMsg`?

Comment: This is call to another function. In this way you can call multiple function by passing parameter. You need to define the argument during function definition to access it.

Comment: sir, if you don't mind please show me an example based on my prblm. I didnt understand this

Comment: Your are just missing this changeColor() function. Just add the changeColor() function in your script, and when you will click on any of the link this function will change your div color.

Comment: Sir this is not working for all cases. I tried out. It is changing the color of only navlnk2

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as per your need. try it.

```js
var num = 1;
function myFunction() {
 var listArry = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
 for(var i = 0; i < listArry.length; i++){
     listArry[i].style.color = "grey";
 }
 if (num==1){
  document.getElementById('navlnk').style.color = "black";
  num=2;
 }
 else if(num==2){
  document.getElementById('navlnk1').style.color = "black";
     num=3;
 }
 else if(num==3)
 {
  document.getElementById('navlnk2').style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById('btn').value = "Save";
  num=1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav2">
    <div class="navtxt container">
        <ol>
            <li class="list" id="navlnk">Assess your risk tolerance</li>
            <div id="b" class="fif"><a href="#navlnk1" onclick="changeColor('navlnk1'); return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 20px;"></span></a></div>
            <li class="list" id="navlnk1">View your plan</li>
            <div id="b" class="fif"><a href="#navlnk2" onclick="changeColor('navlnk2'); return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="padding-left: 20px;"></span></a></div>
            <li class="list" id="navlnk2">Open account</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="btn" type='button' name='add' onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you this is working. If we create another button instead of continue how we modify. I tried but some errors

Comment: Can you be more precise. What you want to do with another button?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Our team was not decided about back button that's why i didn't tell it first time. Now both button working correctly. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Could you please vote my answer if my solution helped you?